# Is there a way to link the weights of my probability to the variables

Tags: python

I am trying to make a rudimentary AI that gives the user three choices from a randomly generated list, and once chosen, would raise the probability of it showing up again.

My previous "solution" was spamming if statements to account for every choice the user could make but quickly realised that it was very time consuming and inefficient.

Currently, I have a list of weights for the probabilities (the actual probability is based relative to the others in the list - the numbers there are arbitrary) :

```
p_red = 100
p_blue = 100
p_yellow = 100
p_green = 100
p_orange = 100
p_purple = 100
```

And code to make it select three of the colours.

```
colourList = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "purple"]
x = (random.choices(colourList, weights=(p_red, p_blue, p_yellow, p_green, p_orange, p_purple), k=3))
```

I have all of this in a while loop so it doesn't reset. The problem I have is that I can make a choice but I cant use the outcome of the choice to influence the probability because the choice that you make is separate to the probabilities.

Can anyone help me?

P.S. I apologise if the answer is easy lol, I understand the basic mechanics of programming but don't have much practical experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you keep both the colors and probabilities in two arrays in the same order you can use the index of the choice to update the probability

```
 chosen_color = random.choices(...)
 color_index = colors.index(chosen_color)
 proba[color_index] = new_proba_value
```